# File copied to /system/bin keeps disappearing

Tags: adb, file-system, htc-one-m8

After copying Sqlite3 to by /system/bin folder, the file disappears.  I can successfully change the folder to rw and modify the file properties on sqlite3.  However, as soon as I remount my /system as ro, the sqlite3 file disappears.  I have attempted this [using these instructions](https://philio.me/installing-sqlite-on-a-rooted-android-phone/), from both a terminal session on the phone and adb session from my pc with the same results.

Here's what I've tried:

```
mount -o remount,rw /system
cp /sdcard/sqlite3 /system/bin (ls confirms that the file is present)
chmod 4755 /system/bin/sqlite3 (SQLite command works)
mount -o remount,ro /system (file is gone)
```

I also tried copying SQLite from my TitaniumBackup folder, but with the same results.  Although, calling SQLite from this folder seems to work.

And, I tried using File Manager with root to copy and set permissions on the files, also unsuccessfully.

And, I have also tried [SQLite Installer for Root](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ptSoft.util.sqlite3forroot&hl=en), but it hasn't worked.

My device is a Sprint HTC One M8, rooted with TWRP, Android 5.0.1.

This question is very similar to [this old, unanswered one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435988/rooted-htc-system-files-wiped-after-reboot) on StackOverflow.

**UPDATE 2015-07-27**:  I have used @Izzy's suggestions and run a logcat and collected the file (actually several repetitions). After searching the files for anything related to any key terms (e.g. sqlite3, mount, chmod, remount, cp...) I can't find anything of obvious value.  Of course, I've never done this before, so I don't have any experience parsing or interpreting these files.  Any other thoughts/directions would be appreciated. FWIW, for the short term, I'm using the TitaniumBackup SQLite file, so my immediate problem is solved-not it's just personal between me and my OneM8!

**UPDATE 2015-07-28:**  This problem affects any file I try to copy to /system/bin-they're all erased/removed upon a reboot.  I also tried from TWRP Recovery's file manager with the same result

Comment: try remount from stepehen sterricson on the play store. just pick what you want remounted, how you want it remounted, and click the logo.

Comment: To get some more info, try the "core steps" again this way: 1) preparation: open your terminal app and `su`, 2) start logging: from your computer, start `adb logcat`, preferably having it write to a file, 3) action: back in your terminal, do the remount/copy/remount, 4) stop logging: cancel the logcat with Ctrl-C, 5) investigate the logs. Hopefully, you find some pointers there.

Comment: @DanB, I have tried Sterricson's Remount and it fails (with no message/log).  FWIW, his Busybox (basic and pro) also fails on install-although when I run Busybox verify it shows as present?!?

Comment: @dav odd. To be honest, I have heard a lot of negative noise for that app

Comment: Is this the case with SQlite3 or with any file that has been tried to be copied into `/system`?